# Fast way to determine if a function is pointwisely or uniformly convergent

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am wondering if there is a fast way that we can determine if a function is pointwisely convergent or uniformly convergent, without having to go through the formal proof?

It doesn't have to be a perfect property. It would be fine as long as it works well heuristically. For instance, a fast way I have so far discovered for determining whether a continuous function is uniformly continuous: if a function is continuous but unbounded (like $\frac{1}{x}$), then it is definitely NOT uniformly continuous.

Is there a similar rule for uniform convergence?

Thanks!

Comment: My finding for uniform convergence so far is that if the difference of the function to its limit: $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ is not constant (something depend on x) and can go up to infinity with x (holding n constant), then it is definitely NOT uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly, the answer is no, because you can create a lot of tricky functions that converge in weird ways, and in fact I'm pretty sure it is possible to create a sequence whose convergence is unproveable (by pegging its convergence on another unproveable statement, e.g. something involving the sum of reciprocals of Godel numbers of true statements).

However, there are a bunch of results about convergence that you can use to make it easier to identify *some* convergent and divergent functions. You've already pointed out some of the tricks for divergence, but one particularly useful result for proving convergence is the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), which states that (roughly) if the function you're looking at always sits between two other functions, and those functions converge to the same value at a particular point, then the function you're looking at also converges to that value.

For example, $-x \leq x \sin x \leq x$ for all $x$, so you can immediately state that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (x \sin x) = 0$ since the other two functions also converge to $0$. There's an equivalent squeeze theorem for sequences as well, and it's often much easier to prove convergence through the squeeze theorem than via first principles.

Comment: Is squeeze theorem also useful for identifying uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes, under the right conditions. If you have a sequence of *functions*, and you can squeeze each of those functions between two other sequences that each converge uniformly, then I'm 99% sure you have uniform convergence of your sequence.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!